# Prove that the interior of the boundary of an open or closed set is empty.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A\subset X$ and $B=Fr(A)$.

I have two questions.

1. How do you prove that if $A$ is open or closed, then $B^\circ=\emptyset$?
2. Why can this not be proven for a set that is both open and closed?

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your definition of boundary?

Comment: @Exodd. $ Fr(A)=\overline{A}\cap \overline{(A^c)} $

Comment: By your definition, $Fr(X) = Fr(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, so even if $A$ is both open and closed,  the interior of $B$ is empty..

Answer (score 0):

$$(Fr(A))^\circ=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{A^c})^\circ=(\overline{A})^\circ\cap (\overline{A^c})^\circ=A^\circ\cap (A^c)^\circ=A^\circ\cap (\overline{A})^c=\emptyset$$

Comment: It’s not necessarily true that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A=\operatorname{int}A$: consider the set $A=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ in $\Bbb R$.